# How to take elements and separate by comma

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a scraper that takes a list of elements, then I go through them and add them to an array, see:

```
try:
                get_tags=driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,'//p[@class="heatmapthemead-tag-links"]/a')

                lista_tags = []

                for tag in get_tags:

                        lista_tags.append(tag.text) 

                tags = lista_tags
        except:
                tags=''
```

The problem is that the result I get is like this: `['tag1' , 'tag2']`

But I need the result like this: `tag1, tag2`

How can I have the output only comma separated ?

Comment: you can use `join` example like `','.join(['tag1' , 'tag2'])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most pythonic way is use `join` function to join list

`','.join(['tag1' , 'tag2'])`

Answer (score -1):

The `['tag1' , 'tag2']` means you are outputting the list instead of every element in the list separated by a comma as you seem to be looking for.

Essentially what you are doing for output is:

```py
print(lista_tags)
```

when instead you want something more akin to:

```py
for ent in lista_tags:
    print(str(ent)+','),
```

Comment: This way  will make an extra ',' at last.